# Dialog.Ask is giving indexoutofboundsExceptions with int[]

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Not working:

```
final Object[] stringsMenu;
Vector auxMenu = new Vector();
final IntVector optionsMenu = new IntVector();
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha");
        optionsMenu.addElement(1);
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha2");
        optionsMenu.addElement2);
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha3");
        optionsMenu.addElement(3);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        try
        {
            int[] optionsintMenu = optionsMenu.getArray();
                    switch (Dialog.ask("Info:", stringsMenu, optionsintMenu, 0))
                    {
                      ...
                    }
                }
            }
        } ..................
```

Working

```
final Object[] stringsMenu;
Vector auxMenu = new Vector();
final IntVector optionsMenu = new IntVector();
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha");
        optionsMenu.addElement(1);
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha2");
        optionsMenu.addElement2);
        auxMenu.addElement("ficha3");
        optionsMenu.addElement(3);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        try
        {
                    switch (Dialog.ask("Info:", stringsMenu, new int[]{1,2,3}, 0))
                    {
                      ...
                    }
                }
            }
        } .....................
```

Is giving me an internal IndexoutofboundsException. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: 1. Please format your code so that it is actually readable to someone that has no masochistic tendencies. ;) 2. I guess `IntVector` is some sort of implementation of `Vector<Integer>`? Have you tried looking at `optionsIntMenu`? My guess is that this array is not really what you expect it to be...

Comment: Oh and 3. Don't do `Vector auxMenu = new Vector();`, but `Vector<String> auxMenu = new Vector<String>();` instead.

Comment: BlackBerry uses Java-ME, so no generics, no ArrayList, no iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getArray()` try to use [`toArray()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/IntVector.html#toArray%28%29).

According to the doc :

**toArray :**

> public int[] toArray()
>
> Retrieves a copy of the underlying store. The resulting array is trimmed.

**getArray :**

> public int[] getArray()
>
> Retrieves the vector values. The array is not trimmed and is not a copy.

**The array is not trimmed**, it's probably why you get an indexOutOfBound

Comment: The most strange thing is that without trimmed when i got out the values they were well , no extra space no null or different size . But it must be that here the Dialog uses an internal rep. of the Vector. Good answer.

Comment: Yeah it's probably linked to the capacity of the Vector, according to the addElement method doc : `The capacity of this vector is increased if its size becomes greater than its capacity.` and the capacityIncrement field : `The amount by which the capacity of the vector is automatically incremented when its size becomes greater than its capacity. If the capacity increment is 0, the capacity of the vector is doubled each time it needs to grow.`